# How do I build libraries for WebAssembly?

Tags: static-libraries, webassembly, static-linking, emscripten, libav

I want to use the FFmpeg libraries (libav) in my WebAssembly project, using Emscripten.

I think I need to build the libraries from source to create ".a" files. (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

I think the first step is to run `emconfigure ./configure` (please correct me if I'm wrong), but I keep getting this error:

```
configure: ./configure
emconfigure: error: './configure' failed: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I think this is because the "configure" file is for Linux not Windows. (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

I have tried to do this using MSYS, Git Bash and CygWin on Windows with the same result.

Is it possible run the configure file on Windows?

Is it possible to build the libraries I need on Windows for WebAssembly?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO, it is NOT possible in Windows.

You MUST use a UNIX environment, NOT an emulator in Windows.

See https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/4354